# Executing generated assembler inline

Tags: javascript, assembly, scheme, inline-assembly, dynamically-generated

I was reading the following presentation:
    http://wingolog.org/pub/qc-2012-js-slides.pdf
which talks about (4,10,19) inline ASM generation as a technique used in Javascript optimisation.

In the following paper:
https://sites.google.com/site/juliangamble/Home/Compilers%20Tutorial%202006-09-16.pdf?attredirects=0&d=1
at page 30 and 31 they talk about using scheme to generate ASM that is subsequently linked and executed in a subsequent OS process.

What about the scenario where you want to generate the ASM and execute it inside your existing process? (ie no subsequent link and execute in separate steps).

I *assume* this comes down to (in C for example) generating the ASM, writing the bytes to an area of memory (code as data) and adding a function header and return (compatible with a C caller (similar to what we see on page 3 of the Goloum paper above). Then we take that data pointer and convert it to a function pointer and call it (code as code - from code as data).

My questions are:

(a) What is the terminology for this inline code generation and execution?

(b) Is there a simple 'hello world' C example of this available?

Comment: I would call it just-in-time (JIT) compilation. A number of Scheme implementations use it, such as Racket and Larceny.

Comment: This is quite similar to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3073653/can-function-pointers-be-used-to-run-data (but with no example) - they call it self-modifying code - which I'm not sure I agree with the categorisation in my case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is quite a good example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4819124/15441). Again they use the terminology of self-modifying code.

Another one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10266596/15441).

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8713627/use-cases-for-self-modifying-code) they give it four categories (use cases):

- Metamorphism
- Trampolining
- JIT compilation
- Security implications (insecure coding/malware)

There is a discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8490616/homoiconic-and-unrestricted-self-modifying-code-is-lisp-really-self-modifyin) about whether LISP is truly self-modifying - and they end up concluding that it is not.